# c# How to downcast an object

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following list of slide objects. Based on the value of object's 'type' var I want to upcast the Slide object in the list. Is it possible?

```
foreach(Slide slide in slidePack.slides)
{
    if(slide.type == SlideType.SECTION_MARKER)
    {
      //upcast Slide to Section
    }
}
```

`Section` extends `Slide` and adds one more parameter.

Comment: Sounds like a downcast to me. Anyway, it's dangerous (or a design flaw) to do this. By downcasting to a more specialised type, you are expecting more from the object than it may be able to handle. If you feel the need to downcast, consider using interfaces.

Comment: Agreed that interfaces can be useful in some of these situations, but I don't think we should say "never downcast". It's not always a design flaw, nor is it necessarily dangerous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the proper way to handle that cast.

Edit: There are ways to design programs to not need the test/cast you are looking for, but if you run into a case where to need to attempt to cast a C# object to some type and handle it different ways depending on success, this is definitely the way to do it.

```
Section section = slide as Section;
if (section != null)
{
    // you know it's a section
}
else
{
    // you know it's not
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can do that:

```
Section section = (Section)slide;
```

...or:

```
Section section = slide as Section;
```

The difference between those is that the first one will throw an exception if `slide` cannot be cast to `Section`, while the second one will return `null` if the cast is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
Section section = (Section)slide;
```

But you shouldn't do that - it's almost always a sign of flawed desgn.

Answer (score 2):

(Putting this as a proper answer instead of a comment to the original post...)

This sounds like a downcast to me. Anyway, it's dangerous (or a design flaw) to do this. By downcasting to a more specialised type, you are expecting more from the object than it may be able to handle. If you feel the need to downcast, consider using interfaces.

Example:

```
class ClassWithX 
{
    public void X() {} 
}

class ClassWithXY 
{ 
    public void X() {} 

    public void Y() {}
}

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassWithX x = new ClassWithX();
        ((ClassWithXY) x).Y(); // Downcast, but x of type ClassWithX does not have Y()
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast it:

```
 Section section = (Section) slide;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Slide slide in slidePack.slides)
{
     if(slide.type == SlideType.SECTION_MARKER)
     {
         Section sec = (Section)slide;

         //use sec.SectionProperty
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as well if you only expect/want to process a single type

```
foreach(Section section in slidePack.slides.OfType<Section>())
{
    // Handle the current section object
}
```